# Yogscast Complete Sphax texture pack not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

When I select the pack from the resource pack list, none of the textures work and all I see are the default textures. I'm using the 64x pack and have assigned over 7GB of RAM to it. Downloaded the pack from [here](http://bdcraft.net/community/pbdc-patches-rel-packs/yogscast-complete-pack-t2859.html). I checked, and both the pack.mcmeta and assets folder are in the folder, as well as pack.png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphax Patches contain *only* the Textures for the Mods. You will still need the corresponding pack for Minecraft itself, and load both of them at the same time.

Post 1.7, you should be able to just load both packs using the resource pack manager.

For 1.6.4 and earlier versions, you will have to merge the packs manually

- Open PureBDcraft Zip file with the Archiving Program of your Choice
- Open your Patch Zip file
- Copy files of the Patch Zip inside the PureBDcraft Zip. Make sure to keep the folder structure and merge folders where necessary. Which `pack.mcmeta` you use shouldn't matter
- Close everything
- Be sure to place PureBDcraft in the texturepacks folder

Comment: I have a minecraft folder in the assets (which contains default textures) and also none of the mod textures load either. Do I still need to follow these steps? (Apologies for not including that information in my question if that information invalidates your answer)

Comment: @imulsion The yogscast pack (from your link) does contain a minecraft folder in assets by default, but it contains *only* the armors from GalactiCraft as far as I can see. Make sure that really everything that should be there is really there, if you didn't do so already. Though if you didn't follow my steps already, it's probably incomplete. If it doesn't work with the merged pack, leave another comment, and update your question accordingly.

Comment: It worked. I love you. That is all